# Windows docker file for dotnet application

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have worked previous on creating docker file for Linux. But i am not sure wrt windows containers. Can someone provide a sample working docker file to run dotnet dll

Comment: there should be no big difference because dotnet core is cross platform(windows, linux). please just try and give error if you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need your Dockerfile to do, you could possibly use the same Dockerfile for both Linux and Windows. For example, the Dockerfile below is for a sample app on the official .NET Docker GitHub repo at
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/03bdd523be6af06c553a03685ad529ec46973b23/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

That Dockerfile will work when targeting Linux or Windows. That's because the tags being used, `6.0`, are multi-arch/multi-platform tags which automatically allow the appropriate image to be used (Linux vs Windows) depending on the environment in which the Dockerfile is being built.

If there are other commands that you need to run that vary between Linux and Windows, you'll need to be more explicit in your question.

Comment: Dotnet publish is returning error npm is not recognised as internal or external command. Npm istall exited with code 9009

Comment: Please let me know powershell command to install npm and nodejs before running dotnet publish command. I have downloaded the msi package for nodejs and copied to my dockerfile. I need powershell command to execute the package